# Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.5.dylib

Tags: macos, macports

I am compiling some C++ code on Mac OX Snow Leopard (MacPorts).

I got error message:

collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 5 [Trace/BPT trap]

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.5.dylib

Referenced from: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.3/lib/libLTO.dylib

Reason: image not found

I know libffi was updated to a newer version which now provides libffi version 6 that I have now.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'sudo port rev-upgrade' first.* This should identify missing / mis-linked files and rebuild the required ports. (Will use pre-compiled binaries rather than build when permitted by licenses and config.)

In general, you may find the mailing list the most productive place to ask these questions. https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users

- actually, do 'sudo port selfupdate && sudo port upgrade outdated' first if you haven't recently.